# How do I initialize a map with initializer list

Tags: c++11, dictionary, stl, initializer-list

I'm stuck with a map initialization problem.
I want a table to access all the directions of my tetris blocks.
I have tried a lot of methods to initialize it, but it seems too complex to be initialized.

This is the error info this time:

错误  C2440   “初始化”: 无法从“initializer list”转换为“std::map,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator>>>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator>,std::allocator>>>>>>” WinApp  c:\codes\learning\winapp\tetris.cpp 44

I wonder how to initialize this table.

in my 
    `block`
class:

```
typedef std::map<shapes, std::vector < std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > > > proj;
static proj dirs ;
```

in the .cpp file:

```
block::proj block::dirs = 

{
{ 6,{ { TL, TC, MR },{ TC, ML, BL } } },
{ 4,{ { TR, TC, ML },{ TC, MR, BR } } },
{ 5,{ { ML, MR, BC },{ TC, MR, BC },{ TC, ML, MR },{ TC, ML, BC } } },
{ 3,{ { TL, TC, ML } } },
{ 2,{ { { ML, BL, MR },{ TC, BC, BR },{ TR, ML, MR },{ TL, TC, BC } } } },
{ 1,{ { ML, BR, MR },{ TR, TC, BC },{ TR, TC, BC },{ TL, MR, ML },{ TC, BC, BL } } },
{ 0,{ { ML, MR,{ 2,0 },{ TC, BC,{ 0,2 } } } } }  // sticks out
};
```

I defined the pairs as const vars for short.

```
const   std::pair<int, int>    TL{ -1,-1 };      /* top left */
const   std::pair<int, int>     TC{ 0,-1 };        /* top center */
const   std::pair<int, int> TR{ 1,-1 };     /* top right */
const   std::pair<int, int>  ML{ -1,0 };              /* middle left */
const   std::pair<int, int>  MR{ 1,0 };               /* middle right */
const   std::pair<int, int>    BL{ -1,1 };       /* bottom left */
const   std::pair<int, int>   BC{ 0,1 };         /* bottom center */
const   std::pair<int, int>     BR{ 1,1 };       /* bottom right */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like misplaced braces in the last line of `dirs` declaration. Try to replace

```
{ 0,{ { ML, MR,{ 2,0 },{ TC, BC,{ 0,2 } } } } }
```

with

```
{ 0,{ { ML, MR,{ 2,0 } },{ TC, BC,{ 0,2 } } } }
```